# kotlin qualifier annotaion is ignored

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

Code below compiles the first time but fails on second build giving:

> Error:SomeObject is bound multiple times:
>
> @Provides @NotNull SomeObject SomeModule.provideSomeObject()
>
> @Provides @NotNull SomeObject SomeModule.provideSomeScopedObject()

It seems that the compiler ignores `Qualifier` annotations on consecutive builds.

It does not help when component and module are written in java as annotation is ignored in `Main` class.

```
@dagger.Component(modules = arrayOf(SomeModule::class))
interface Component {
    fun inject(main: Main)
}

class Main {
    @field:[javax.inject.Inject SomeScope] lateinit var obj: SomeObject
}

@dagger.Module
class SomeModule {

    @dagger.Provides
    fun provideSomeObject(): SomeObject {
        return SomeObject("noScope")
    }

    @SomeScope
    @dagger.Provides
    fun provideSomeScopedObject(): SomeObject {
        return SomeObject("someScope")
    }
}

data class SomeObject(val name: String)

@javax.inject.Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class SomeScope
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try removing this line `@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)`. As far as I know Dagger 2 requires `RUNTIME` retention (which is the default one in Kotlin, hence no need to specify it explicitly).

Comment: thanks, now the question is why `SOURCE` retension worked fine on java